# How does pcntl_fork work in PHP?

Tags: php, fork, pcntl

I'm confused about [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/pcntl_fork) in PHP.

I think it does multi-threading, but how does it work and how would I use it in a script?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19546588/632951

Answer (score 62):

PCNTL can not make threads. It only "forks" current PHP process. What does it mean? When you call `pcntl_fork()`, current process is split into two processes. Whole namespace of parent process is copied into the child and both processes continue with execution in parallel with only one difference: `pcntl_fork()` returns child's PID in parent and `0` in child.

Some hints:

- It is disabled by default. If you manage to enable it, then do it for CLI only. Never ever use it with web server! It will behave in non-deterministic way. It can also bring whole machine down. Please, leave it disabled and read on.
- Communication between processes is possible but horrible (via
  serialized object in shared memory).
- File descriptors (and database
  connections) are shared, this causes problems very often. **You have to reconnect your DB after forking** or you will get errors like `MySQL server has gone away` from all forked processes when first of them closes the connection.
- Parent process have to wait for children to finish or it will leave zombie
  processes consuming system resources behind.

Here's example [from documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php):

```
<?php

$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // we are the parent
     pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children
} else {
     // we are the child
}
```

But remember, PHP is just scripting language. It's not designed for parallel computing. You could do better job with simultaneously running CRONs, message queues or program in lower-level language, depending on your needs.

Forked PHP program is very hard to read, understand and debug. Maintaining that program will be a nightmare.

Don't make mistake and avoid forking. You don't need it. What you really need is asynchronous task runner. Good news, there is [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and [nice tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-rabbitmq-php/) ;-) You can also try promising RabbitMQ library called [Bunny](https://github.com/jakubkulhan/bunny)

PS: Using message queues instead of forking gives you one more advantage. You can process the queue with multiple servers and scale horizontally as your traffic grows.

EDIT 2019-03-07

I have played a lot with asynchronous concurrency framework `amphp` and I have to mention it here. If you really need to run async non-blocking tasks in single request, I consider `amphp` to be the best solution today. It uses concept of php generators (`$value = yield $promise`) to execute human-readable code without reactphp-like promise hell.

https://amphp.org/

Comment: Would you recommend creating daemons with forking ?

Comment: ReactPHP uses forking when no c library is installed, so sure that there is a easy way to handle fork.

Comment: I work in a project where forking occurs. Im not developing forking functionality as it is written and works fine. Anyway the project is a big fin and it scales and it is maintainable as well. Im not saying forking is the optimal solution, but it works. Im guessing too you would need quite an experience in this if you would like to apply this in real life serious project